# Mongoose conditional findByIdAndUpdate based on a parameter

Tags: mongoose

I have a complex mongoose query that I need help with.

This is the document that I am working with:

```
{
  cretedAt: 2023-09-17T21:27:49.000Z,
  _id: new ObjectId("64d40eccb8ff7a6f56d094b6"),
  key: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
  name: 'New Name',
  owner: new ObjectId("64d0f4cdbb1cee9e07ebc808"),
  access: [
    {
      name: 'New Access Name',
      right: 'readonly',
      _id: new ObjectId("64c2e464c024b5efb9583c23")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

And I have a function that receives the userId and the data to query the elements:

```
async renameGateway ( userId: string | Types.ObjectId, { gatewayId, name }: RenameGatewayDto ) {
    const gateway = await this.gatewayRepo.findOne( {
      _id: gatewayId,
      $or: [
        { owner: new Types.ObjectId( userId ) }, // Find if userId matches the owner
        { access: { $elemMatch: { _id: new Types.ObjectId( userId ) } } } // Find if userId exists in the access array
      ]
    } );

    if ( !gateway ) {
      throw new NotFoundException( "Gateway not found" );
    }

    const updateGateway = await this.gatewayRepo.findByIdAndUpdate(gatewayId,
      {[query to update]}
    );

    return updateGateway;
  }
```

The ideea is to update the name property of the document if the `userId` is the owner, or, if not, to update the object inside the `access` array that the `_id` is the `userId`.

Can someone help me with the query/pipeline? It can be for a findOneAndUpdate function aswell. I prefer the findByIdAndUpdate, but I read it's not as versatile.

I would also like a conversion for the `findOne` function into a findById, since the `$elemMatch` is not allowed there for some reason. This part is optional.

Here is somthing that I tried and throws me an error:

```
const updateGateway = await this.gatewayRepo.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: gatewayId,
        $or: [
          { owner: new Types.ObjectId( userId ) }, // Check if userId matches the owner
          { access: { $elemMatch: { _id: new Types.ObjectId( userId ) } } } // Check if userId matches an _id in the access array
        ]
      },
      {
        $set: {
          name: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ "$owner", new Types.ObjectId( userId ) ] },
              then: 'New Name', // Replace with the desired new name for the owner
              else: '$name' // Preserve the existing name for the owner
            }
          },
          "access.$[elem].name": {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ "$access._id", new Types.ObjectId( userId ) ] },
              then: 'New Access Name', // Replace with the desired new access name
              else: '$access.$[elem].name' // Preserve the existing access name
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

The error:

```
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{
  '$cond': { if: { '$eq': [Array] }, then: 'New Name', else: '$name' }
}" (type Object) at path "name"
    at SchemaString.cast (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:606:11)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.applySetters (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1220:12)
    at SchemaString.castForQuery (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:690:15)
    at castUpdateVal (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:575:19)
    at walkUpdatePath (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:295:22)
    at castUpdate (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\castUpdate.js:110:7)
    at model.Query._castUpdate (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4710:10)
    at model.Query._findOneAndUpdate (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3326:23)
    at model.Query.exec (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4430:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at GatewayService.renameGateway (E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\dist\main.js:2404:31)
    at E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at E:\Gitlab\babylon-data-registery\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```